# Invalid number format model

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT decode(to_number(to_char(01-04-2016, 'mm')),
      1,
      to_number(to_char(01-04-2016, 'yyyy')) - 1,
      2,
      to_number(to_char(01-04-2016, 'yyyy')) - 1,
      3,
      to_number(to_char(01-04-2016, 'yyyy')) - 1,
      to_number(to_char(01-04-2016, 'yyyy'))) FROM DUAL;
```

whenever i execute this statement it shows invalid number format model.

Comment: `01-04-2016` isn´t a valid number. `to_char` either expects a `date` or a `number`. and this value doesn´t represent either of them

Comment: but already i have given to_char(01042016,'mm') but the same error is showing

Comment: @NirmalyaRoykarmakar yeah, because you are trying to parse a number with a date format which doesn´t work.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach it´s actually vica verse, as it´s not a `date` it expects a `number`, but `mm` isnt a valid format to format a `number`.

Comment: Can u give a example plz?

Comment: to_char(01-apr-2016,'mm') is it the right format to do?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of how to represent literal values in PL/SQL. `01` and `04` and `2016` are all *numbers*, which means `01-04-2016` is an arithmetic expression; `'01-04-2016'` is a *string*, and `date'2016-04-01'` is a *date*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is invalid currently, as [to_char](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) expects a `number` or `date`, but the plain number `01-04-2016` doesn´t represent either of these.

The follow up mentioned in your comment `to_char(01042016,'mm')` wont work either, as the given number can´t be parsed with `mm` as it does expect a valid `numberFormat` and not a `dateFormat`, which `mm` isn´t.

In order for your query to work, wrap the pure date into a `to_date` and mention the current `dateFormat` given by the `char`:

```
SELECT decode(to_number(to_char(to_date('01-04-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'mm')),
      1,
      to_number(to_char(to_date('01-04-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'yyyy')) - 1,
      2,
      to_number(to_char(to_date('01-04-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'yyyy')) - 1,
      3,
      to_number(to_char(to_date('01-04-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'yyyy')) - 1,
      to_number(to_char(to_date('01-04-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'yyyy'))) 
FROM DUAL;
```